# Information icon on button created using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a button in javascript. Now I can add button text on to it but with information icon.

I have created a button using javascript like this

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 var t = document.createTextNode("Click me");
 x.appendChild(t);
 document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Now, I know &#9432 is html entity of information icon

```
<button style="font-size:24px">Click me&#9432</button>
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfh39.png) from this code

The above code will produce the required thing i.e button name + icon.

but if i do this

```
var t = document.createTextNode("Click me"+"&#9432");
```

it will not work.It will print text(&#9432) only on button.I want to achieve same thing in javascript created button using javascript only.

I have also tried

```
x.classList.add("fa fa-info-circle fa-6")
```

font awesome class for info icon but it throws error.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('fa fa-info-circle fa-6') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.
```

Is there any way to use html entities in javascript or any other simpler method to achieve the same.

Thanks,

Comment: Get rid of the '+' between the strings "Click me" "&#9432" will work same as "Click me &#9432" should also work.

Comment: I tried that also but that doesn't work. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: After trying "Click me" "&#9432" it throws error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" and "Click me &#9432" print the text as it is. Thanks,

Comment: Can you post your updated code as I'm curious to see why you are getting missing ).

Comment: <body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">try</button>
</body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 var t = document.createTextNode("Click me" "&#9432");
 x.appendChild(t);
 document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>           I tried this code on www.w3schools.com and was getting error.

Comment: ("Click me" "&#9432");  is the same as ("Click me&#9432");   They will end up concatenated.   I would suggest that when writing scripts you get into the habbit of surrounding the script in a try{ /*Your code here*/ } catch(e) { alert(e); } clause, this will give you additional information when an error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either change the `innerHTML` of the button instead of creating a text node, since text nodes display text as-is:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD ANOTHER BUTTON</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("button");
    x.innerHTML = "Click me &#9432;"
    document.body.appendChild(x);
  }
</script>
```

Or, you can use the unicode value of the character, in your case, it's `\u24d8`:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD ANOTHER BUTTON</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Click me \u24d8");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: for javascript there is unicode value for each html entity?

Comment: @ShubhankGupta Yes, here is a list of so many symbols with their unicode value: https://unicode-table.com/en/#enclosed-alphanumerics.

Comment: Ok, That is new thing got to know. It is really helpful. Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you should change to make it work for font awesome:

```
x.classList.add("fa", "fa-info-circle", "fa-6");
```

Docs link for **classList** methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods

Final Result

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Click me");
    x.classList.add("fa", "fa-info-circle", "fa-6");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

Comment: This additional information will help me in future assignments for other different icons which doesn't have html entities. For right now above other methods worked for me.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The `createTextNode` method creates a text node and shows contents as plain text. To display HTML, you need to use the `innerHTML` property. Also, you missed the semicolon.

```js
function createButton(html) {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = html;
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

createButton('Click me &#9432;');
```